# sql groupby 1 column then count percentage of column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named T:

| Industry | stock | trdType | nr | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TMT | Tencent | active | 30 | 1 |
| TMT | Tencent | normal | 20 | 2 |
| TMT | Tencent | passive | 50 | 3 |
| TMT | Alibaba | active | 20 | 4 |
| TMT | Alibaba | normal | 50 | 5 |
| TMT | Alibaba | passive | 30 | 6 |

is there any SQL trick to generate a result like (column names are automatically generated by enum?):

| Industry | stock | active_nr | active_nr% | normal_nr | normal_nr% | passive_nr | passive_nr% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TMT | Tencent | 30 | 30% | 20 | 20% | 50 | 50% |
| TMT | Alibaba | 20 | 20% | 50 | 50% | 30 | 30% |

Thank you,

Edited:

the math behind %:

1. first group by stock, for example "Tencent"
2. then sum(active, normal, passive) should be a total (say 100 here), so the percentage of Tencent active_nr should be 30/(30+20+50） = 30%.
3. Same logic for Tencent normal_nr and passive_nr
4. Same logic for Alibaba-wise

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE script for source table. Does `(Industry, stock, trdType)` is defined as UNIQUE?

Comment: I don't understand the math behind the expected percentages.  Can you please explain it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, thanks for the reply! I have edited the math logics for the new columns

Comment: @Akina Hi Akina, thanks for the reply! Actually table T is generated from another query and there is no constraint for the generated table, just select-wise and group-by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT
    Industry,
    Stock,
    MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'active' THEN nr END) AS active_nr,
    100.0 * MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'active' THEN nr END) / SUM(nr) AS active_nr_pct,
    MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'normal' THEN nr END) AS normal_nr,
    100.0 * MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'normal' THEN nr END) / SUM(nr) AS normal_nr_pct,
    MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'passive' THEN nr END) AS passive_nr,
    100.0 * MAX(CASE WHEN trdType = 'passive' THEN nr END) / SUM(nr) AS passive_nr_pct
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Industry,
    Stock;
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, clear and working, very much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to group by Industry and Stock and then calculate the percentages by TrdType.
I assume the percentages are calculated over the group of trdtype by Industry/stock

```
Select pvt.Industry, pvt.stock, pvt.[active_nr], pvt.[normal_nr]
FROM (
    SELECT  Industry
            ,stock
            ,trdType
            ,sum(nr)
    FROM MyTable
    group by Industry, stock, trdType
    ) t1
    PIVOT
    (
        sum(nr)
        FOR trdType IN ([active_nr],[normal_nr],[passive_nr])
    ) as pvt
```

Then you can use this result to get your percentages as it will have the structure you need.
I have used this is the past as a CTE in that purpose and there has to be other ways

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i have added some math logics. I am not sure whether this is correct as it may not need to group by Industry, stock, trdType. Overall you need to sum all trdType based on (Industry, stock).

Comment: And may I ask that which part generates the percentage? thanks

Comment: I used this as a Common Table Expression for my query, but you can put this in a temporary table and then do your math with a new query